# segmentation fault when using su or sudo

Tags: bash, segmentation-fault, su, gdb

example of the problem:

```
$ su
Segmentation fault
$ sudo ls
Segmentation fault
```

I tried to compile sqlite3 from source earlier. I don't know what libraries it installed. This may be the reason why this is happening.

I tried `strace su` and it ends with the following:

```
...
fstat64(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=17964, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 20788, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 6, 0) = 0xb7295000
mmap2(0xb7299000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 6, 0x3) = 0xb7299000
close(6)                                = 0
mprotect(0xb7299000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb72f9000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
set_tid_address(0xb758a728)             = 11144
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I try `gdb su` and try to run, it gives me `Cannot find new threads: generic error`. I looked online for a solution to the problem, encountered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702628/gdb-cannot-find-new-threads-generic-error) thread, and then tried running `LD_PRELOAD=/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 gdb su` (as suggested in the thread). When I then tried to run it again, it gave me the same error.

Based on the strace, I think there is some problem with how it's threading, but I have no idea how to fix this. Is there some way to reinstall the basic bash utilities?

Here's more information about my system:

```
$ uname -a
myhost 3.2.0-37-generic-pae #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 15:51:02 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

(I'm pretty sure the hardware is 64bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aptdcon`, which communicates with `apt-daemon` via `dbus` so it doesn't need `su` or `sudo`, to reinstall the damaged packages. Probably your best chance is to reinstall ALL the packages.

First, make sure there is no broken install pending a fix:

```
aptdcon --fix-install
```

Also make sure there is free space available on your disk:

```
df -h
```

Then, get your currently installed package list:

```
echo \"$(dpkg --get-selections | grep install | cut -f 1)\"
```

Save that for later, on a text editor of something. Then, call `aptdcon` like this, using the full package list:

```
aptdcon --reinstall "package1 package2 package3..."
```

I'm telling you this way because `aptdcon` won't be able to reinstall some packages for various reasons, so you will have to strip them out if `aptdcon` cries about that, and try again, probably more than once.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just having to reinstall the sqlite packages via aptcon, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem, but the root cause was slightly different. I had been testing Kerberos and had something misconfigured in my /etc/krb5.conf. I discovered via strace that sudo was segfaulting shortly after reading that file so I figured there was an issue with my configuration file. I didn't track down a specific variable but one thing that stood out was that I had the default_domain variable empty in the krb5.conf like so

```
[libdefaults]
   default_realm =
```

This may have cause some sloppy code in sudo to make a zero length string and mishandle it somehow causing the SIGSEGV. I didn't try to debug it any further since this wasn't the correct setting. I simply deleted my /etc/krb5.conf.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that a pam module from samba is causing this.

If that's the case, then this should fix it:

- Reboot the machine and choose to boot to the recovery mode. If you can't see the recovery mode, then you first need to choose the 'Advanced options for' option.
- Choose "drop into root shell" from the recovery menu
- Execute the command: dpkg --purge libpam-smbpass
- Execute the command: dpkg --purge libpam-winbind

Then you should be able to use 'su' and 'sudo' again.

You then may want or need to do a

- sudo apt-get -f install

to help fix any remaining broken packages.

If you need the libpam-smbpass and/or libpam-winbind package, or have a broken 'samba' package, you may find that you have to delete or rename /var/lib/samba/secrets.tdb:

- sudo mv /var/lib/samba/secrets.tdb /var/lib/samba/secrets.tdb.old

Source/Related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/260687

Answer (score 0):

If you have the problem as the OP encountered, you cannot do what Jorge Suárez de Lis suggested, as it will throw a dependencies error.

So,

```
aptdcon --reinstall "libsqlite3-0"
```

and

```
aptdcon --install "libsqlite3-0"
```

returns the error message:

ERROR: org.debian.apt.TransactionFailed - error-cache-broken: The following packages have unmet dependencies:

While doing THIS:

```
aptdcon --fix-depends
```

will fix it, and su and sudo will work again.