# Unable to do su or sudo after upgrade from 13 to 14

Tags: 14.04, 13.10, upgrade, sudo

I have upgraded from 13 to 14, and in the upgrade process a lot of errors occurred. Now I can't access root(via su command) or execute something like `sudo apt-get install something`.

> **NOTE**: This is not a duplicate of **[segmentation fault when using su or sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260353/segmentation-fault-when-using-su-or-sudo)**
>   .  I have tried the answers posted there but the did not work. Please see **EDIT 1** below.

If I try:

```
    sudo apt-get install XXX
```

I get this error:

```
    Errore di segmentazione (core dump creato)
    Segmentation fault (core dump created)
```

How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT 1:**

I just tried `aptdcon --fix-install` posted in the answer here: [segmentation fault when using su or sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260353/segmentation-fault-when-using-su-or-sudo), and it returned the following result:

```
ERROR: Operazione di pacchetto non riuscita
Installazione o la rimozione di un pacchetto software non riuscita.

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-winbind:amd64:
 libpam-winbind:amd64 depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3); however:
  Package samba-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libpam-winbind:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba:
 samba depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3); however:
  Package samba-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of system-config-samba:
 system-config-samba depends on samba; however:
  Package samba is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package system-config-samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of winbind:
 winbind depends on samba (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3); however:
  Package samba is not configured yet.
 winbind depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3); however:
  Package samba-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package winbind (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba-dsdb-modules:
 samba-dsdb-modules depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3); however:
  Package samba-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package samba-dsdb-modules (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsmbclient:amd64:
 libsmbclient:amd64 depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3); however:
  Package samba-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libsmbclient:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-samba:
 python-samba depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3); however:
  Package samba-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python-samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba-vfs-modules:
 samba-vfs-modules depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3); however:
  Package samba-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package samba-vfs-modules (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

After that I tried to run:

```
echo \"$(dpkg --get-selections | grep install | cut -f 1)\"
```

and

```
aptdcon --reinstall "package1 package2 package3..."
```

using the generated list, returning the following result:

```
ERROR: org.debian.apt.TransactionFailed - error-cache-broken:  I seguenti pacchetti presentano dipendenze non soddisfatte:                     

libnss-winbind: Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3 è installato
                Depends: winbind (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3 è installato
                Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3 è installato
                Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma non è installato
libpam-smbpass: Depends: samba-common (= 2:3.6.18-1ubuntu3.3) ma 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3 è installato
libpam-winbind: Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3 è installato
                Depends: winbind (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3 è installato
                Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma non è installato
libsmbclient: Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma non è installato
python-samba: Depends: python (< 2.8) ma 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 è installato
              Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) ma è un pacchetto virtuale
              Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma non è installato
samba: Depends: heimdal-hdb-api-8 ma è un pacchetto virtuale
       Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3 è installato
       Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3 è installato
       Depends: python (< 2.8) ma 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 è installato
       Depends: python2.7:any ma è un pacchetto virtuale
       Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma non è installato
samba-common-bin: Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3 è installato
                  Depends: python2.7:any ma è un pacchetto virtuale
                  Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma non è installato
samba-dsdb-modules: Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma non è installato
samba-vfs-modules: Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma non è installato
smbclient: Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3 è installato
           Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma non è installato
winbind: Depends: samba (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3 è installato
         Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3 è installato
         Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3) ma non è installato
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [segmentation fault when using su or sudo](http://askubuntu.com/questions/260353/segmentation-fault-when-using-su-or-sudo)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The asker tried the answers there but they did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably that you have damaged files on the system.  Perhaps something went wrong during the upgrade, or the upgrade was halted before it was finished (possibly due to a power loss, or running out of disk space?)

Segmentation fault is a serious error that should not occur in normal situations.

This [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260353/segmentation-fault-when-using-su-or-sudo) suggested the use of:

```
aptdcon --fix-install
```

And this may then lead you to have to reinstall some other packages - see that other answer for more details.

---

After seeing your updated information it looks as if this is the samba issue mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/421856/54256) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=995542) where upgrading/reinstalling samba might break logins (including sudo).

It is described in this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/260687).

So, you can try to purge all samba related packages then re-install samba (if needed, or just remove it completely).  In particular, you'll need to purge `libpam-smbpass`.

Because you can't use sudo, you'll need to do this via single user mode which Ubuntu makes available through "recovery mode" at the boot screen.

Quoting from that bug report:

```
- Reboot and choose the "recovery mode" from the boot selection menu
- Choose "drop into root shell" from the recovery menu
- Execute the command: dpkg --purge libpam-smbpass
```

Comment: No power or disk space problem...

I have added the result of the commands in the Question

Comment: In that case, it could be the samba related issue mentioned [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/421856/54256) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=995542).  Updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, recovery, mounted partition, purged the 2 packets(ssmbpass and winbind), "-f install", moved secrets.tdb and now works perfectly!

Thanks!